# how to put objects of a class into a list in c# windows form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created a class named Field. In a windows form you can add a object of this class. and in another windows form, I wanna show those objects. What should i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Field class**

```
public  class field
{

}
```

**Form1**

```
public partial class FORM1 : Form
{
    public FORM1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        field objectField = new field();
        Form2 objForm2 = new Form2(objectField);
    }
}
```

**Form2**

```
public partial class FORM2 : Form
{
    public FORM2()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public FORM2(Object o)
    {

       // here you can show you field class object and do what you want
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few options: 
**Option 1.** You can pass your `Field` in the constructor of your second `Form` like so:

```
Field _field;

public NameOfSecondForm(Field f)
{
    _field = f;
}
```

Then in your first form before you show the second form:

```
Form form = new NameOfSecondForm(yourField);
form.Show();
```

**Option 2.** Use a second static class to save and retrieve data:
Create new file and replace all contents with this:

```
public class DataMidpoint
{
    public static Field field { get; set; }
}
```

To pass data, do this in your first `Form`:

```
DataMidpoint.field = yourField;
```

Then retrieve the data in your second `Form`:

```
Field field = DataMidpoint.field;
```

I hope this helps!